# ¿Cómo recibir un array en un procedimiento de forma correcta en oracle?

Tags: oracle

Tengo un problema con una función que recibe un array, he buscado por todas partes pero no he podido encontrar una respuesta concreta...

El código para obtener el array es el siguiente:

```
CREATE TYPE arreglo IS VARRAY(3) OF INT;
/
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION array_example
RETURN arreglo
AS
    variable_arreglo arreglo;
BEGIN
    variable_arreglo := arreglo(0,0,0);  
    variable_arreglo(1) := ROUND(dbms_random.VALUE() * 19) + 1;
    variable_arreglo(2) := ROUND(dbms_random.VALUE() * 19) + 1;
    variable_arreglo(3) := ROUND(dbms_random.VALUE() * 19) + 1;
    dbms_output.put_line('Valores en arreglo:');
    -- recorriendo arreglo
    FOR i IN variable_arreglo.first..variable_arreglo.last LOOP
        dbms_output.put_line('Posicion '||i||': '||variable_arreglo(i));
    END LOOP;
    RETURN variable_arreglo;
END;
/
```

El código del procedimiento es el siguinte

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE seleccion(ingreso VARRAY)
IS
DECLARE variable_arreglo VARRAY;
BEGIN
    UPDATE AEROPUERTO
    SET id_principal = NULL;
    
    UPDATE AEROPUERTO
    SET id_principal = ingreso;

    --select * from aeropuerto;
    FOR X IN (SELECT * FROM AEROPUERTO)
    LOOP
        IF AEROPUERTO.id_principal = AEROPUERTO.id THEN
            BEGIN
            UPDATE aeropuerto
            SET id_principal = NULL;
            END;
        END IF;
    END LOOP;
END;
/
```

El procedimiento debería recibir el array y asignar un valor aleatorio de él en una columna de una tabla, pero estoy teniendo problemas para poder hacerlo

Alguien me podría explicar que estoy haciendo mal? :(

El error que obtengo con ese código para el procedimiento es el siguiente:

3/1       PLS-00103: Se ha encontrado el símbolo "DECLARE" cuando se esperaba uno de los siguientes:     begin function pragma procedure subtype type      current cursor delete    exists prior external language
Errores: comprobar log de compilador

Comment: La cláusula DECLARE sobra dentro del procedimiento "seleccion"
OJO: los UPDATES les hace falta la claúsula WHERE.